# How to beat Muffet?

Tags: undertale

I tried to fight her and wait it out for 17 turns. But I can't survive for that long. How do I dodge her 'pet' and the attacks? Fighting her is nearly impossible and I bought stuff in the ruins from muffets. I just want to pass her!

Answer (score 4):

[Muffet](http://undertale.wikia.com/wiki/Muffet/In_Battle) has a number of attacks, all of which force you to move between three "strings". There's no secret in learning how to dodge attacks with this setup - you'll just have to learn how to avoid the attacks. Practice makes perfect!

There are some other ways to skip the fight though. If you buy an item from Muffet in Hotland, she will refuse to fight you, which skips the battle entirely. However, her items cost nearly 10k gold. Another way to avoid the fight is to use a spider doughnut/spider cider during the fight with her. These can be purchased for a much more reasonable price in the Ruins at the beginning of the game.

If you're okay with trying to last the 17 turns required to get her to spare you, you can bribe her to reduce the damage taken on your next turn. However, the cost of the bribe increases the more you do this.

Answer (score 2):

This is a method I used for beating Muffet:

Use the Struggle ACT for the first 3 turns; this halves the bribe price. Keep sparing her for the next 3 turns. On turn 6 (when she summons her pet), use the Pay 5G option in ACT. Keep sparing her until turn 12. On turn 13 (when she summons her pet again), use the Pay 45?G option in ACT. Keep sparing her until turn 16. On turn 16, get your HP to 20 (or MAX). Then on turn 17 (when she summons her pet for the last time and is last turn), Use the Pay 75?G option in ACT. The pattern for the last one is (spider amount) 1 bottom, 2 up, 1 up, 2 bottom (repeats and gradually gets faster).